# Application Framework like sugarcrm

Tags: php, frameworks, sugarcrm

I love sugarcrm .. It's great at building applications quickly. I see it more of a application framework that's been used to create a CRM package. It's easy to create a module. It plugs in the menu, the lists are all done, sub panels are a breeze. Granted, you can't change the look and feel easily... But hey .. it works.

I've now used suagrcrm to build back end management systems for websites that actually don't have a CRM aspect.. Sugar is great because it has everything "ready to go" (user management, lists etc).

I was wondering if there are any other frameworks out there like SugarCRM that allow you to easily create a module.

I don't want to go too low level, like zend, Cake PHP etc.  I'm looking for something that has all the "holes" already, and can be customised / modules added. really easily.

Hope that makes sense

Blake

Comment: Have you tried PyroCMS or ExpressionEngine?